# My browser goes unresponsive when I try to execute this JS

Tags: javascript, while-loop, infinite-loop

I use this code to add or remove certain nodes from a page I have on my site:

```
function nextChild() {

var elem = document.getElementById('formtbody');
var a = 0;
var b = elem.childNodes[a];
var node = b.style.display;
var lastnode = 0;

while (node !== "none") {
    (lastnode++);
    (a++);
}
(lastnode++);
var c = lastnode;
var therightnode = elem.childNodes[c];
return therightnode;
}

function addRemoveClass(option) {

var elem = document.getElementById('formtbody');

if (option === "add") {
    nextChild().style.display = "";
} else if (option === "remove") { 
    elem.lastChild.style.display = "none";
    elem.lastChild.form.reset();
}
}
```

I execute with `addRemoveClass("add")` and `addRemoveClass('remove')`

But when I try to add, it goes unresponsive.  I think it's getting stuck in an infinite loop but I can't tell.

I've tried JS Lint but it didn't find anything either.

What I'm trying to do with this script is find the first child node of `formtbody` with the `style="display:none;"` attribute and make it visible.

Comment: Yep, it's in an infinite loop. Your `while (node !== "none")` is a problem. Only `a` and `lastnode` change in that loop. Why would `node`'s value suddenly become anything different? I'll let someone else tell you about the best way of accomplishing your DOM traversal, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is an infinite loop if `node !== "none"` when the loop starts:

```
while (node !== "none") {
    (lastnode++);
    (a++);
}
```

Nothing in the loop changes the value of `node` so once the loop starts, it will never stop.

Also, this syntax is odd and not required:

```
(lastnode++);
```

Remove the parens so it's just:

```
lastnode++;
```

Using the jQuery library (which makes cross browser DOM manipulation sooo much easier), here's some code to find the first item in a list that is set to display: none.

Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Um95a/

and the code:

HTML:

```
<ul id="container">
    <li class="show">First item</li>
    <li class="hide">Second item</li>
    <li class="show">Third item</li>
    <li class="show">Fourth item</li>
    <li class="show">Fifth item</li>
</ul>
<br><br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.hide {display: none;}
```

Javascript (run after page is loaded):

```
function findFirstDisplayNoneChild(parent) {
    var result = null;
    $("#" + parent + " li").each(function() {
        if ($(this).css("display") == "none") {
            result = this;
            return(false);    // break out of each() function
        }
    });
    return(result);
}

var hidden = findFirstDisplayNoneChild("container");
if (hidden) {
    $("#result").html("Hidden Element: '" + hidden.innerHTML + "'");
} else {
    $("#result").html("No hidden elements found");
}
```

Or, any even simpler version of the code using the :hidden selector:

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Xsgmu/

```
function findFirstDisplayNoneChild(parent) {
    return($("#" + parent + " li:hidden").get(0));
}
```

Comment: but 'node' does change because it changes when 'a' changes, right?

Comment: `a` is just a numeric variable initialized to zero.  Manipulating it has nothing to do with `node`.  You would have to assign something to node within the loop or call a function within the loop that changes the value of node.

Comment: But doesn't it?  I mean, 'b' is dependent on the value of 'a', and 'node' depends on 'b'.

Comment: No, those statements have already been evaluated before the loop.  If you want them re-evaluated inside the loop, then you need to put them in the loop so they are executed within the loop.

Comment: What is the overall objective of the nextChild function?

Comment: What I'm trying to do with this script is find the first child node of formtbody with the style="display:none;" attribute.

Comment: so what would do to make that work? The first childnode is shown but the other nine are hidden by default.  i may just end up using a bunch of `if` and `if else` statements.

Comment: I provided a version of what you asked for using jQuery in my answer.  I don't do cross-browser DOM manipulation without a helper library.

Comment: That's a lot of code... try `$('#container li:hidden').show();`.

Comment: I just used a bunch of `if`s and `if then`s

Answer (score 1):

```
while (node !== "none") {
    (lastnode++);
    (a++);
}
```

is an infinite loop since the value of node does not change in the loop. If `node !== "none"` when the loop is reached it will never be equal to "none"

Answer (score 0):

```
function nextHiddenChild(element) {
   var child = element.firstChild;
   while (child && child.style.display !== 'none') {
      child = child.nextSibling;
   }
   return child
}

function addRemoveClass(option) {
   var elem = document.getElementById('formtbody');

   if (option === "add") {
      elem = nextHiddenChild(elem);
      if (elem !== null) {
         elem.style.display = '';
      }
   } else if (option === "remove") { 
      elem.lastChild.style.display = 'none';
      elem.lastChild.form.reset();
   }
}
```

But I recommend you use a library like jQuery. Seriously, you're wasting time learning the nitty gritty of direct DOM manipulation. If you have a job to do besides academic learning the DOM inside and out, such as getting a site built, then go get jQuery or prototype or MooTools or any other library and use it. Later, if you have time, you can come back and see how it all works.

Also, addressing your questions about the variables `a` and `b`: they are just scalar values. They're not reference types, not objects. Just because you used `a` in an earlier statement to get a value out of an array doesn't somehow bind that array to `a`'s updated value.

```
var arr = ['x', 'y', 'z'],
   a = 0,
   value;
value = arr[a];
alert(value); //'x'
a += 1;
alert(value); //notice value hasn't changed, and why should it? You haven't assigned anything to it since last time.
value = arr[a];
alert(value); // now it's 'y'
```