# How to debug Javascript Unresponsive Script error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sometimes when I reload a website in Firefox and reload it displays an Unresponsive Script error, but I'm not sure how to debug it because the problem appears to be in jQuery itself.

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding.
>   You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script
>   will complete.
>
> /assets/jquery.js?body=1:349

How can I debug this?

Comment: Is this a website you're working on? If so, I'd take a look at your jQuery selectors. Are you using classes instead of IDs? Are you caching frequently-accessed jQuery results? For example, if you have a TABLE element containing a report that returns hundreds or thousands of rows, and you use jQuery to either add a CSS class or attach a click event handler to each TR or any of its TDs, jQuery will take too long to finish its job since JavaScript runs in one thread in the Web browser, thus blocking the UI and the dreaded unresponsive JavaScript warning will appear.

Comment: @MarioJVargas I am not using 100 or 1000 of rows, I am Just Setting the Height of a div in page on DOM Insertion and Removal, below is a function for that written in coffeescript

  $(".blockCont").bind "DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved", ->
    setMaxHeight()

But don't know how to debug the exact problem.

Comment: How large is your page? I'm thinking that the problem is the class selector in `$(".blockCont")`. A class selector is not specific enough, so jQuery has to go through each element in the DOM tree until it finds a match. This can hinder performance.

Comment: If you're binding to only *one* element, use an ID over a class. For example, ` $("#myTargetElement")` is much faster. If it's a series of elements you're looking for, you can modify your selector so it is more specific. For instance, ` $(".someParentCssClass .anotherCssClass div.blockCont")`. jQuery uses right-to-left association, so elements on the right side have to be more specific than elements on the left.

Comment: Thanks @MarioJVargas I will try by replacing the elements with ID selector Might that will help

Comment: Start commenting out lines of JavaScript until you stop getting the Unresponsive Script notification. Then you've found your performance problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My browser goes unresponsive when I try to execute this JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714917/my-browser-goes-unresponsive-when-i-try-to-execute-this-js)